# How to optimize dynamic metadata fetching with Firestore and async function in Next 13 to avoid exceeding Firebase free quota?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

In my Next 13 app i've created a dynamic meta data with firebase/ Firestore. but then i left the app unclosed and it exceeds the free quota. i haven't done any activities. before the metadata i used to fetch Firestore datas without the async function that introduced in Next 13 for SSG, SSR... . but now in order to create a dynamic metadata i needed to fetch asynchronously. i'm not sure if leaving my pages open calls them or not.

so my question is does opening a page and leaving it open for several time forces the page to reload? if so how can i make it fetch only once? and does using async function re-fetches everything? and finally after deploying my app does the dynamic metadata fetch every time someone visits or it only fetches while search engine crawlers are crawling and then only updates if there is a change?

I know i've asked too many questions at once, but PLEASE help me out if you can. Thanks.

This is where i used the dynamic metadata in `app/vehicle/[vehicleid]`

```
export async function generateMetadata({ params: { vehicleid } }) {
  // const [datas, setDatas] = useState({});

  const vehicleData = getVehicle(vehicleid);

  const [vehicle] = await Promise.all([vehicleData]);

  return {
    title: `${vehicle.title} a ${vehicle.year} ${vehicle.make}, ${vehicle.bodyType} ${vehicle.condition} car for sell in Ethiopia.`,
    description: `don't miss out a ${vehicle.year} ${vehicle.make}, ${vehicle.bodyType} ${vehicle.condition} car for sell in Ethiopia.`,
    openGraph: {
      title: `${vehicle.title} a ${vehicle.year} ${vehicle.make}, ${vehicle.bodyType} ${vehicle.condition} car for sell in Ethiopia.`,
      description: `don't miss out a ${vehicle.year} ${vehicle.make}, ${vehicle.bodyType} ${vehicle.condition} car for sell in Ethiopia.`,
      images: vehicle.images[0],
    },
    robots: {
      index: true,
      follow: true,
      nocache: false,
      googleBot: {
        index: true,
        follow: true,
        noimageindex: false,
      },
    },
  };
}
```

and this is what my getter looks

```
import { doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore/lite";
import { db } from "../firebase";

export default async function getVehicle(vehicleid) {
  const docRef = doc(db, "vehiclePosts", vehicleid);
  const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

  return docSnap.data();
}
```

and inside `app/vehicle/[vehicleid]/page.jsx`

```
async function VehicleGroup({ vehicleid }) {
  const date = new Date();
  const vehicleData = getVehicle(vehicleid);
  const year = date.getFullYear();
  const [vehicle] = await Promise.all([vehicleData]);

  return (
   //...here is the rest of the code
);
}
export default VehicleGroup;
```

before using it with metadata and async function i used to fetch it in client side with hooks like these

```
function VehiclePage({
  params: {
    vehicleid
  }
}) {

  const [datas, setDatas] = useState([]);

  const getData = async () => {
    const docRef = doc(db, "vehiclePosts", vehicleid);
    const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

    setDatas(docSnap.data());
  }

  useEffect(() => {

    getData();

  }, []);

  return (
    //...code here
  );
}

export default VehiclePage;
```

Comment: Your `useEffect` doesn't have a dependency array, which means that it runs on every render. And since you update the state in there, it causes an infinite loop. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70569588/very-high-number-of-reads-in-firestore-database-in-my-react-project

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen the `useEffect` is the previous way i used to do. but i'm just fetching it asynchronously as i showed in the first code. and i haven't provided a dependency so that it will only run once.

Comment: If a `useEffect` has no dependencies, it runs on every render. To have it run only once, you need to pass an empty dependency array. The question I linked shows how.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yes i did do that `useEffect(() => { } , [])`

Comment: Ah, now I see. I fixed the indentation of the code block to make that clearer. I recommend using a tool like prettier or https://beautifier.io/ to do this yourself going forward.  I reopened the question in hopes that somebody else spots the problenm.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i opened my billing status and checked after i made a visit to a detail page of my app which only fetches a single doc. but it is showing me that it made 11 reads. why is this happening?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen as i mentioned in my code above maybe the count is increasing b/c i've made separate fetches for the page itself and for the dynamic metadata. even if that's the case it should've been 2 reads. and maybe next js does SSR so if it fetches for the next waiting time still it should be 4 read max. why is it counting it as 11 reads? i'm not even querying and there is no sub collection. only string, bool, array, date and int. I really have no idea. PLease give me an insight on this

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen as i've been replying i left the page opened and when i recheck it now it reached 990 reads. and after less than a minute it reached 1.5k reads.

Comment: The most common cause of confusion for devs new to Firestore is that any operations made by the Firestore console are also charged, and the console needs more document reads than most realized. So: don't keep the Firestore document console open when doing tests like this. --- Also note: you can edit comments, so avoid posting many of them. And be sure to put significant information in your question rather than (just) in comments (where hardly anyone will see them)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i only opened the usage section. does that have an affect?

Comment: No, the usage panel doesn't cause charged document reads.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen the console was not opened and now it reached 10k Reads. just by opening a single doc in my page

Comment: That really sounds like an endless loop in your code. Put a breakpoint on each place that reads from Firestore, and run in a debugger to check when/how often those hit.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i am not running it inside a loop. i even tried it in production mode and console logged it so i can see how many times the function is called and it only called it once.